# Google Compute Engine Migrating from Development to Production Effectively

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I have two compute engines. One is made for development (**website-dev**) and one for production (**website**). All on Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

I want to migrate (clone) the development server (**website-dev**) contents and update the production server (**website**) contents with the new developments (apache configurations, html, cron jobs, etc...). I am mostly interested in leaving the Compute Engine configurations (storage, processing, hardware) all alone. I just want to clone the contents on the server.

**My process:**

1. Develop **website-dev** under a unique domain (*example.dev*).
2. Once developed, clone the entire contents of the **website-dev** server and update **website** (*example.com*) with its clone (ensuring updated host configurations for new domain)
3. Continue to build on **website-dev** and update **website** again in future.

**Options:**

1. Exchange the DNS settings and point **website-dev** to **website** and **website** to **website-dev** in the DNS settings.
2. Similar to above, exchange the Compute Engine Network Interface IPs which exchanges the IP of the Compute Engines.
3. Flip disks somehow? Or use Snapshots.
4. Manually update **website** with all the updates done on **website-dev** (*long downtime and higher probability of errors in my opinion*)

**Questions:**

1. What's best practice for this? and what's the most effective way to migrate updates from a development server to a production server.
2. Are there any search engine or other implications from flipping IP address or DNS settings if this is the best option?

I want to avoid downtime, minimize production errors and trouble shooting and be able to upgrade easily even with small updates.

I'm essentially looking for a copy from server to server button. Is there a best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I would not use any of your options. Source code, configuration files, etc. should get in a repository (GitHub, Google Source Repositories, GitLab, etc.). Secrets should be stored in Secrets Manager, KMS, Vault, etc. Environment-specific configurations should be in environment variables, .env files, etc. When you want to deploy a production machine, you pull and configure or better yet have build and deploy pipelines. Never copy from one machine to another. There is a risk of side effect dependencies that you might not be tracking/documenting or might be challenging to simply copy.

Comment: You should have three isolated systems in different projects: DEV, STAGING, and PRODUCTION.